# Visual Studio constantly "Loading" / "Updating" something, causing high CPU utilization

Tags: visual-studio-2017, cpu-usage

I have been running into this issue often, where Visual Studio seems to get stuck "Loading" and "Updating" SOMETHING constantly, causing VS to run at 50% CPU utilization indefinitely.

All I do is simply load the dotnet core solution.  The dependencies are loaded as normal, but then the lower status bar shows Loading/Updating back and forth and slows things down significantly.  Have not been able to figure out how to fix it other than deleting my entire solution folder, and getting a brand new repo.  Then it will go away for a while, soon to return.

I now have a co-worker that has had the same thing happen on his, so I know its a thing.

I have a video of this happening here:  https://youtu.be/dSs-EWNnFWM

Anyone have this issue?